# Picture attached to an object only viewable at certain angles

Tags: 3d-view, viewlayers

Basically I have a picture attached to one side of an object.
Depending on the angle I am looking at it is sometimes viewable, half viewable, or not viewable at all.
Thanks as always for your help everyone.[image]

Comment: when you say that it is attached, what do you mean? Are you using an Image Texture and a UV? Maybe you have faces overlapping?

Comment: Ah yes , so it's not really attached. Its actually slightly higher than the face of the object. So i don't think it should be overlapping anything. Its just a jpg. Is there a way to properly attach it to the surface of an object? Thanks.

Comment: you should better unwrap your object and give it a material with an Image Texture node, with your image loaded, and put your UV over the image in the UV Editor

Comment: Thanks moonboots, i've done that now. It's projected onto all the sides now though. I have managed to get  one face perfect but now want the other faces to go back to normal. I'm checking tutorials just now to work it out. thanks.

Comment: in Edit mode, select the other faces, then go in the UV Editor and make them small so that they lay over a completely black surface. Or give them another material

Comment: Yep, worked that out. :-D Thanks Moonboots, you rock.

Comment: I rock'n roll!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have faces overlapping. You should better unwrap your object and give it a material with an *Image Texture* node, with your image loaded, and put your UV over the image in the *UV Editor*. If you don't want the other faces to display the image, in *Edit* mode, select the other faces, then go in the *UV Editor*, scale them down and move them so that they lay over a completely black part of your image. Or give them another material.